# How to make the Rounded corners of the client app in WindowedApplication?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, rounded-corners

In my application,`showFlexChrome` is set as true in `WindowedApplication`,and the `*-app.xml` is setted as follows

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome> 
<transparent>true</transparent> 
<visible>true</visible>
```

I know how to make the top border rounded corners with follow codes:

```
borderStyle="solid" cornerRadius="8"
```

But I cannot find a method to make the bottom border of my app window rounded-corner. Suggestions would be appreciated!

Regards

Comment: We're not using AIR anymore, but I remember these settings sort of being a pain.  Different combos of styles; build... AND, making a change to that xml file seemed to always require a 'clean' of the project to get changes to register... but that may have been an air 1.0 issue.  That said, looking at that old project I noticed that we commented out transparent and visible and put those properties as properties of the windowedApplication mxml tag.  Do you have a controlBar at the bottom of the Windowed? What happens when you put all of your styles in css instead of mxml-inline properties?...

Comment: @jeremy.mooer,it seems there's not any controlbar:(.Maybe I should convince the business consultant to give this feature up.Thanks any way.:)

Answer (score 1):

I've used a picture with rounded corners as a background image. Of course chrome was set to none and transparent to true.